# How to create a file and attach it email?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, sendmail, email-attachments

I'm trying to send an email via my app (using react and node).

My problem is how to attach file to the message?

I need first to create a file and then to attach it, but no need to save it only to send.

By searching I found only approach which assume the file to attach is exists.

Do you have a good example for me to implement that?

Thank you!

Comment: Which library do you use to send emails?

Comment: I use email.js.